# Clarification for Theta notation in complexity analysis. Θ(g)

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity, complexity-theory, asymptotic-complexity, big-o

When we talk about Θ(g) are we referring to the highest order term of g(n) or are we referring to g(n) exactly as it is?

For example if ***f(n) = n<sup>3</sup>***. And ***g(n)=1000n<sup>3</sup>+n*** does Θ(g) mean Θ(1000n<sup>3</sup>+n) or Θ(n<sup>3</sup>)?

In this scenario can we say that *f(n)* is Θ(g)?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a plain English explanation of "Big O" notation?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/487258/what-is-a-plain-english-explanation-of-big-o-notation)

Comment: @DmitriChubarov I believe Theta and Big O represent very different aspects of the complexity of an algorithm.

Comment: One answer in particular details the relations between three kinds of notations for complexity classes http://stackoverflow.com/a/6620071/1328439

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Θ(*g*) yields *sets* of functions that are all of the same complexity class. Θ(1000*n*<sup>3</sup>+n) is equal to Θ(*n*<sup>3</sup>) because both of these result in the same set.

For simplicity's sake one will usually drop the non-significant terms and multiplicative constants. The lower order additive terms don't change the complexity, nor do any multipliers, so there's no reason to write them out.

Since Θ(*g*) is a set, you would say that *f*(*n*) ∈ Θ(*g*).

NB: Many CS teachers, textbooks, and other resources muddy the waters by using imprecise notation. Lots of people say that *f*(*n*)=*n*<sup>3</sup> **is** O(*n*<sup>3</sup>), rather than *f*(*n*)=*n*<sup>3</sup> **is in** O(*n*<sup>*3*</sup>). They use = when they mean ∈.

Answer (score 1):

theta(g(n)) lies between O(g(n)) and omega(g(n))
if g(n) = 1000n^3 + n

first lets find O(g(n)) upper bound
It could be n^3, n^4, n^5 but we choose the closest one which is O(n^3).

O(n^3) is valid because we can find a constant c such that for some value of n
1000n^3 + n < c.n^3

second lets see omega(g(n)) which is lower bound
omega says f(n) > c.g(n) 
we can find a constant c such that
1000.n^3 + n > c.n^3

Now we have upper bound which is O(n^3) and lower bound which is omega(n^3).
therefore we have theta which bounds both upper and lower using same function.

By rule : if f(n) = O(g(n)) and f(n) = omega(g(n)) therefore f(n) = theta(g(n))

1000.n^3 + n = theta(n^3)